# how to dynamically append json values using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting the json response from the service as follows.

```
[  
   {  
      "ProductName":"Apple iPhone 4",
      "ProductUrl":"/~/media/upload/4jpg.jpg",
      "ProductPrice":"499"
   },
   {  
      "ProductName":"Apple iPhone 4S",
      "ProductUrl":"/~/media/upload/4s.jpg",
      "ProductPrice":"650"
   }]
```

By using jquery,I want to add these values into the html dynamically.

HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="" id="resultImg" width="125" height="125" />
        <div class="caption caption-text">
            <p id="name"></p>
            <p id="price"></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:
I have written the following code where I'm loop through the json result and i wanna append it.I'm not getting the correct output.it just appends only the last result.where i am doing the mistake?

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/webapp/products/service", function (data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.info(json);
    var htm;
    $.each(JSON.parse(json), function (idx, obj) {
        console.info(obj.ProductUrl);
        var htm = htm + $("col-xs-2").append($("#resultImg").attr("src", obj.ProductUrl)).append($("#name").val(obj.Name));
    });
    $(".row").html(htm);
});
```

Comment: Did you forget to post "the following code"?

Comment: sorry i have attached the code

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with `var htm = htm + $("col-xs-2").append(...)`. `append` doesn't return a string, so it makes no sense to concatenate it.

Comment: sorry copy paste from net.It might be wrong.just tel lme how to append json result to html using jquery

Comment: Are you intentionally using `JSON.stringify`? I'm not understanding how that would work.

Comment: why do you convert data to json then parse it back to object again?

Comment: If you want to make multiple objects, you shouldn't be appending the result of a selector. That just finds the existing object and moves it to the new location, it doesn't make a copy of it. You could use `.clone()` to make a copy first. But you need to make the IDs unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/webapp/products/service", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
        $('<a href="#">').append(
            $('<img>', {
                "class": 'resultImg',
                src: obj.ProductUrl,
                height: 125,
                width: 125
            }),
            $('<div class="caption caption-text">').append(
                $('<p>', { 
                    "class": "name",
                    text: obj.ProductName 
                }),
                $('<p>', { 
                    "class": "price",
                    text: obj.ProductPrice 
                })
            )
        ).appendTo('.col-xs-2');
    });
});
```

I've replaced the `id`s with `class`es because you can't have duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is to use the data template and them fill the data for each item. The extendable solution is create the javascript object to construct the display list item.

Below is the basic solution:
Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = '[{"ProductName":"Apple iPhone 4", "ProductUrl":"/~/media/upload/4jpg.jpg","ProductPrice":"499"},{  "ProductName":"Apple iPhone 4S","ProductUrl":"/~/media/upload/4s.jpg","ProductPrice":"650"}]';

    // find the template
    var origin_template = $('#template');

    // loop the data
    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(index, obj) {
        var dest_template = origin_template; // this like the copy the template html code. but return the jquery object.

        // set the attribute and html text for the target node.
        dest_template.find('.resultImg').attr('src', obj.ProductUrl);
        dest_template.find('.name').html(obj.ProductName);
        dest_template.find('.price').html(obj.ProductPrice);

        // append the html content to the really display list place.
        $('#row').append(dest_template.html());
    });

    // after the loop, remove the tempate node. [This is optional]
    origin_template.remove();
});
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="row">
    <!-- Your really display list place -->
</div>
<!-- Your tempalte -->
<div id="template" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="" class="resultImg" width="125" height="125" />
            <div class="caption caption-text">
                <p class="name"></p>
                <p class="price"></p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```